# How can i run jobs on multiple environment with if statement in git actions?

Tags: github

I want to run jobs in 3 environment (a,b,c) like this

.github/workflows/main.yml

[image]

and i want to use {if statement} on these environments.

EX)
if runs-on = a :
run: { commands}

but i can't find any documents about this problem.
Does anyone help? ㅠㅠ

Comment: Note: you'll need to pick one of github and gitlab, as their actions are somewhat different. You tagged this with three tags (git, github, gitlab) and at most two of them apply (if you manage to use the common subset of github and gitlab). Git does not have "actions", in this sense, and does not use YAML.

Comment: @torek Oh it's about github actions . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif
I think this document might work for you